# comparing multiple fields of n objects for common values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, comparator

Basically i have a form that I have to prepopulate based on common field values from the object ids select. Eg. I have object with 4 fields (a,b,c,d, could be more). if objects of ids 1, 2, 3 (could be more than 3) are selected, how should I go about comparing all the fields of every selected object in order to prepopulate the form with common values?

I've looked into the Comparator class but it looks like it compares two objects at once (could be multiple fields) which means that if I have n objects selected, it could mean a lot of looping?

I've also considered doing a sql select with distinct and then based on # of rows returned I would know if the field values were the same or not. This would however, mean that I have to make as many sql distinct calls as there are fields which also sounds cumbersome as well as the fact that I'd be doing logic in database instead of application...

I'm using hibernate, spring and java so am wondering if I'm just missing a feature that could do something similar for this?

At the moment I'm using something like

```
CollectionUtils.collect(objectList,TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getA"));
```

and doing it for each form field  and then checking the array for repeated values which doesn't seem optimal at all either...

any help/hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. How does "comparing" and "prepopulate" fit together? Are you trying to pre-fill the form with the most common value present in the database, on a field-by-field basis?

Comment: You could write your own comparator, which would have `n` methods as the amount of attributes you need to compare. I think that's a simple solution for your problem. Don't forget that, if you have `m` objects, then you would have  `m` times `n` validations.

Comment: @Andreas yes I'm trying to prepopulate the formfield only if all select objects hold the same value for that field (so a form might have some prepopulated values and blank for others) sry for being unclear!

Comment: @aribeiro sorry could you please clarify? How does that method differ from what I am currently using? I would still have to iterate through every field and create the arrays of fields in order to do the comparison wouldn't I?

Comment: Well, it depends. Is the number of fields in your form dynamic? Because if it isn't you don't need an array of fields. Just create a method for each field you want to validate. From the description you made, the objects are always of the same type. Therefore, you could have something like: `public boolean isFieldAEqual(List<MyObject> myObjects);`.

Comment: @aribeiro no the number of fields in my form is not dynamic so yes I could do that. but what about the actual comparison itself? wouldn't I still have to make n arrays of field (eg. [a1,a2,a3], [b1,b2,b3]) in order to compare?

Comment: @ElisaC, no, there's no need of several arrays of fields. Just one method per field where you could do `obj1.getFieldA().equals(obj2.getFieldA())` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using Java 8 streams:

```java
public class Test8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObj[] testData = {
                new MyObj(1, "X", 3.14, "Larry"),
                new MyObj(2, "X", 3.14, "Curly"),
                new MyObj(3, "X", 3.14, "Moe"),
        };
        System.out.println("A = " + findCommon(testData, MyObj::getA).orElse(null));
        System.out.println("B = " + findCommon(testData, MyObj::getB).orElse(null));
        System.out.println("C = " + findCommon(testData, MyObj::getC).orElse(null));
        System.out.println("D = " + findCommon(testData, MyObj::getD).orElse(null));
    }
    private static <T, R> Optional<R> findCommon(T[] data, Function<? super T, ? extends R> getterMethod) {
        Set<R> values = Arrays.stream(data)
                              .map(getterMethod)
                              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return (values.size() == 1
                ? Optional.ofNullable(values.iterator().next())
                : Optional.empty());
    }
}
class MyObj {
    private final int    a;
    private final String b;
    private final double c;
    private final String d;
    MyObj(int a, String b, double c, String d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return this.a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return this.b;
    }
    public double getC() {
        return this.c;
    }
    public String getD() {
        return this.d;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
A = null
B = X
C = 3.14
D = null
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using `Set` is an easy solution, but it always has to scan all objects.

If you have many objects, it may be good for performance to stop scanning as soon as you find differing values:

```java
private static <T, R> Optional<R> findCommon(T[] data, Function<? super T, ? extends R> getterMethod) {
    R onlyValue = null;
    for (T obj : data) {
        R value = getterMethod.apply(obj);
        if (value == null)
            return Optional.empty();
        if (onlyValue == null)
            onlyValue = value;
        else if (! value.equals(onlyValue))
            return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.ofNullable(onlyValue);
}
```

Comment: I think this may work perfectly / could be more optimal than my previous method.  besides the stream though, it looks like we go about it similarly (I also make the array to a set to check for size ==1) haven't read up on arrays.steam but is it beneficial in that  I don't need to instantiate an array for each field? will try implementing this and report back. Thanks!!